# Splitting and tallying substrings within mixed integer-string data

Tags: perl, split

Input Data (example):

```
40A3B35A3C
30A5B28A2C2B
```

Desired output (per-line) is a single number determined by the composition of the code 40A3B35A3C and the following rules:

```
if A - add the proceeding number to the running total
if B - add the proceeding number to the running total
if C - subtract the proceeding number from the running total
```

`40A 3B 35A 3C` would thus produce 40 + 3 + 35 - 3 = 75.

Output from both lines:

```
75
63
```

Is there an efficient way to achieve this for a particular column (such as `$F[2]`) in a tab-delimited .txt file using a one-liner? I have considered splitting the entire code into individual characters, then performing if statement checks to detect A/B/C, but my Perl knowledge is limited and I am unsure how to go about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `split` with a capture, the captured group is returned from split, too.

```
perl -lane '
    @ar = split /([ABC])/, $F[2];
    $s = 0;
    $s += $n * ("C" eq $op ? -1 : 1) while ($n, $op) = splice @ar, 0, 2;
    print $s
' < input
```

Or maybe more declarative:

```
BEGIN { %one = ( A =>  1,
                 B =>  1,
                 C => -1 ) }
@ar = split /([ABC])/, $F[2];
$s = 0;
$s += $n * $one{$op} while ($n, $op) = splice @ar, 0, 2;
print $s
```

Comment: I do not fully understand how this works. What is $op doing and why is the splice needed?

Comment: Also, if a fourth letter, for example 'D', was introduced and behaved like C (i.e. subtraction) - could this be added without major modification of the line? Likewise, if the fourth letter was to be completely ignored in the summation?

Comment: @AnnaSchumann: `splice` removes the first two elements from the array. $op is the letter, $num is the number.

Comment: @AnnaSchumann: Introducing a new letter is possible in both solutions. You need to add it to the character class in the regex, and in the first solution, you have to change the ternary operator condition. In the second one, you just add it to the %one hash with the corresponding factor (1 for add, -1 for subtract, 0 for ignore).

Answer (score 1):

When working through a string like this, it's useful to know that regular expressions can return a list of results.

E.g.

```
my @matches = $str =~ m/(\d+[A-C])/g; #will catch repeated instances
```

So you can do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    my $total;
    #break the string into digit+letter groups.
    for (m/(\d+[A-C])/g) {
        #separate out this group into num and code. 
        my ( $num, $code ) =  m/(\d+)([A-C])/;
        print "\t",$num, " => ", $code, "\n";
        if ( $code eq "C" ) {
            $total -= $num;
        }
        else {
            $total += $num;
        }
    }
    print $total, " => ", $_;
}

__DATA__
40A3B35A3C
30A5B28A2C2B
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lne 'push @a,/([\d]+)[AB]/g;
           push @b,/([\d]+)[C]/g;
           $sum+=$_ for(@a);$sum-=$_ for(@b);
           print $sum;@a=@b=();undef $sum' Your_file
```

Answer (score 1):

how it works

- use the command line arg as the input
- set the hash "%op" to the
  operations per letter
- substitute the letters for operators in the
- input evaluate the substituted input as an expression

---

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %op=qw(A + B + C -);
$ARGV[0] =~ s/(\d+)(A|B|C)/$op{$2} $1/g;
print eval($ARGV[0]);
```